# How to bind to a different datacontext then the inherited one for the style value?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, attached-properties

Instead of using many DataTriggers with MulitBinding to set the background color of a ListViewItem:

```
 <DataTrigger Value="4" >
                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource WaitStatus}">
                        <Binding Path="Checkin" />
                        <Binding Path="Checkout" />
                        <Binding Path="Notseen" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GreenBrush}" />
            </DataTrigger>
```

I am attempting to use an attached property to return the Brush color for the ListViewItem background. The code looks something like:

```
<Style x:Key="listViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="v:ListViewItemBehavior.MyValue" Value="{Binding testvalue}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=(v:ListViewItemBehavior).Background}" />
```

My goal is for the first setter to deliver the DataContext of the ListViewItem to the attached property at v:ListViewItemBehavior.MyValue. The attached property then calculates the background color and places the result in ListViewItemBehavior.Background.

The second setter is then to pull the background color from the ListViewItemBehavour and set the ListViewItem's background color from it.

The attached property, ListViewItemBehaviour works correctly to set the Background color, but I can't get how to return this color back to the XAML for the second setter.  The {Binding...} of the value in the second setter always looks for the v:ListViewItemBehavior in the DataContext of the ListViewItem--and I can not get it to look in the ListViewItemBehaviour  for the Background color.

How does one use a different datacontext for the Setter Value property then the inherited datacontext from the ListViewItem?  (syntax please).

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `RelativeSource` of the Binding to `Self`, i.e. the styled ListViewItem:

```
<Setter Property="Background"
    Value="{Binding Path=(v:ListViewItemBehavior).Background,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

Comment: As it turns out, Background is a dependency property of the ListViewItem, so no explicit setter is needed if the background is changed from within the attached behavior. :)